# Laravel - route leading to a closure

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am not new to MVC, but am new to Laravel. I have managed to install it on Windows 8.1 with WAMP. I go to the root URL (`http://localhost/public/`) and get the Laravel logo and the 'You have arrived.' line of text.

Now I want to play around a bit, [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick) tells me that the code below should work.

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('users', function () {
    return 'users!';
});
```

I should get the text `users` when I navigate to `http://localhost/public/users` instead I get a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code

Comment: hmm why do I get a 404? Do I need to re-run something after I make my change?

Comment: Did you set up your web server per http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls ?

Comment: Have you tried using `/users` instead of `users` ?

Comment: I am not sure why it's not working for you, but I just copied your code to my local installation, and it worked as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in route file should be like this

```
Route::get('/users', function () {
    return 'users!';
});
```

Give it a try!

Comment: Worked, strange that the documentation did not mention that pre-slash. Thanks.